# Contributor edits published post and sends for review - post is made private?

Tags: posts, editor

We recently upgrading from WordPress 4.9 to WordPress 5.3 with the new Gutenberg editor.

Previously, I could publish a post, a contributor may make a post-publish edit which doesn't immediately reflect on the published post until I go in and approve/publish it. This seems to be correct procedure.

However, what happens now is that I publish a post, a contributor makes a post-publish edit and sends for review. The post is then automatically taken down until I go in and approve the edit and it's made live again.

What causes this? Is there a way to go back to the 4.9 method?

Comment: It sounds like you must have had a custom workflow in place, perhaps a plugin. WP Core behavior has always been, Contributors can only create new posts, they cannot edit published posts at all. Even if you had edited the Contributor role so they could edit a published post, when they submit any changes for review, that changes the post status to Pending, so it is taken down from the site. This has long been a problem with WP - no way for users to make pending edits without un-publishing the content.

Comment: Interesting! I do have a plugin to edit user permissions and have given contributors "edit published posts" permissions. In the past it didn't un-publish the content but maybe that was some form of bug rather than an intended feature. For now I have removed the permission and have gotten them to pass it to an editor.